# PHPExcel reading Excel 2010 Template file with chart

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I have the following code, which is being run in CodeIgniter.

The template file aol.xlsx contains a chart in Excel 2010. When the file saved to aoltest.xlsx the chart has been removed by Excel but all other data is intact. On opening the file aoltest.xlsx Excel gives the error

`Removed Part: /xl/drawings/drawing1.xml part.  (Drawing shape)`

I am running WAMP on windows 8

Here is my code.

```
        $this->load->library('excel');
        $fileType = 'Excel2007';
        $fileName = 'D:/excelfiles/aol.xlsx';
        $fileName2 = 'D:/excelfiles/aoltest.xlsx';

        // Read the file
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);
        $objReader->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($fileName);


        // Write the file
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, $fileType);
        $objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
        $objWriter->save($fileName2);
```

This is my data table

```
    201401  201402  201403  201404  201405  201406  201407
a   74      42      12      98      64      37      74
b   16      19      100     28      85      40      1
C   66      13      9       41      92      90      38
D   44      35      42      38      81      38      43
```

******Update*******

By changing the column labels above to strings rather than numeric values everything worked like a charm. The reason for the YYYYWW representation is important however and so a fix to allow integers as column headers would be very much appreciated or documented that you should not use integers (May be it is already documented and I just haven't seen it).

---

I have seen a lot of other people complaining about this on many forums and in not a single instance have I found anyone who reports that the issue is fixed. Can anyone confirm that they got this to work and in which case what platform / OS were you using?

Comment: What version of PHPExcel? What type of Chart? Are any errors being logged? Can you provide a working example to demonstrate the problem? If I don't know about an issue, how can I be expected to fix it? If I don't have some way of testing the problem, how can I fix it?

Comment: I downloaded the zip file from github. The only example I can give is the code above, which as documented, opens a working xlsx file containing a chart and resaves it with a corrupt chart. Not sure what else I can provide other than a screencast. PHPExcel does not generate any errors. Can you confirm if you are able to open a Excel2010 document that contains a chart and then resave including the chart? If so can you provide operating details so that I can try to test.

Comment: I can confirm that there's a whole host of example files containing charts in the /Examples folder of the distribution that work perfectly adequately for loading and saving. You should be able to run those codes yourself to see.

Comment: Are the aol.xlsx and aoltest.xlsx files from github too? They're not files that I remember being art of the distribution..... given the myriad of options that can be implemented in an Excel file, it's possible that something in that file is failing

Comment: I will give the examples a try. But the excel files were just simple column charts created from scratch with very basic data. I will let you know how I get on with the examples.

Comment: @MarkBaker I have found the problem. My chart is a stacked column chart. The column labels are integers made up from YYYYWW i.e. 201418. After some trial and error I found that changing these column labels to strings solved the issue. Excel seems happy to have column names as integers it is just when PHPExcels parses the chart that it corrupts the spreadsheet. Is there any way this could be catered for? Some other users may have suffered from the same problem and not realised this was the issue. I will update my original question to display the data table.

Comment: It probably can be catered for, but I'll need to write some code to do so; it's probably not something that can be a quick 5-minute fix

Comment: No worries, now that I know the issue I can work around it. Do you have any idea which file the relevant code is in. I might be able to submit a patch.

Comment: It's most likely to be either Reader/Excel2007/Chart.php or Writer/Excel2007/Chart.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was being caused because PHPExcel does not support chart column labels of type Integer. After changing the column labels to Strings in my Excel template everything worked fine.

Comment: thanks, can you tell me where to set chart column labels to string? is `chart column labels` mean the x labels of the chart?